# How to distinguish these two parts

Tags: grammar

Both nursery rhymes, selected by James Orchard for a folklore society in 1842, and collection of fairy stories which were written by Grimm Brothers, **swiftly translated into English in 1823,** soon rocket to popularity with the young, **quickly leading to new editions.**

Dose “Swiftly translated into English in 1823” modify both nursery rhymes and fairy stories? Or just modify collection of fairy stories.

And the same question, does “quickly leading to new editions.“ modify both of them or just fairy stories.

I’m appreciate for your help!

Comment: Is the quote correct? Does it have an article before "collection of fairy stories"?

Answer (score 1):

There would be no point mentioning the nursery rhymes if they were not also the subject of the sentence, but it was only the Grimm fairy stories which were translated (in 1823) – James Orchard's *The Nursery Rhymes of England* was published in 1842.

So the sentence can be broken down as

> Both
>
> (1) nursery rhymes, selected by James Orchard for a folklore society in 1842,
>
> and
>
> (2) [a] collection of fairy stories which were written by Grimm Brothers, swiftly translated into English in 1823,
>
> soon rocket to popularity with the young, quickly leading to new editions.

Comment: wow，thanks again. It was clear now!

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept the best answers: and please read the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).